# Generate random number between 0 to 10000 in c#

Tags: random, numbers

I'm using c# to generate 1000 random number between 0 to 10000. The output need to be two decimal places , and be dispaly as following

```
1   18.92
2   874.32
3   7182.56
```

Here is my code :

```
            Random random = new Random();
            float randomNumber = random.Next(0, 10001);
            string rndnumber = randomNumber.ToString("0.00");
            for (int i = 1; i<= 1000; i++)
            {
                for (int count = 1; count <= 1000; count++)
                {
                    writer.Write("{0},\n {0:0.0}", count, rndnumber);
                }
```

But so far my output look  like this:

1,
 1.02,
 2.03,
 3.04,
 4.05,
 5.06,
 6.07,
 7.08,
 8.09,
 9.010,
 10.011,
 11.012

What did I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out by myself , use `double` and `Math.Round` to get two decimal

Here is the answer:

```
            Random random = new Random();



                for (int count = 1; count <= 1000; count++)
                {
                    double r = Math.Round((random.NextDouble() * 10001),2);

                    writer.WriteLine("{0} \n {1}",count, r);
                }
```